# Probability mass function

Tags: distributions

The probability mass function of a random variable $X$ is 0 except at the point $X=0,1$ and $2$. at these points it has $P(0)= 3C^2$; $P(1) = 4C-10C^2$; $P(2) = 5C-1$ for values of $C>0$.

i) Determine the value of $C$,

ii) compute the values of $P(X<2)$ and $P (1<X ≤ 2)$.

iii) Suppose that the random variable $X$ assumes three values $0, 1$ and $2$ with probabilities $1/3, 1/6,$ and $1/2$ respectively. Obtain the distribution function.

Comment: Your question needed some editing to make the equations clear and fix a symbol that caused part of the question at the end to be cut off. If you need to make any other changes feel free to do so.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off topic because the poster has not described their understanding or what they've attempted per community guidelines.

Comment: You need a self study tag.

Comment: I disagree with AdamO because the question can be viewed as a problem in elementary probability which in my interpretation can fall under the category of probability theory which is in the community guidelines.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Comment: @Michael Please discuss such disagreements on meta.  You are in an extremely small minority here: see the stated reason for closing.

Comment: @whuber I was just raising the point to let the OP know.  I know that my position is a stretch and I can understand the arguments for closer.  I see my statement as a way to be transparent to the OP rather than to argue with the five that chose to close.  So I do not think this should be discussed separately on meta.

Comment: @whuber Now that I can see the reason for closure is because the question is written in a way to request and answer.  So I now concur with the decision to close. I also think that if the OP can rewrite the question in a way that is not demanding and adds the self study tag there is a possibility to reopen but I do not see that it would be appropriate for anyone to add to my answer since it is self study.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: i) Recognize that P(0)+P(1)+P(2)=1 and do the necessary algebra.

ii) Just need to use the value of C from part i) So add P(0) + P(1) for P(X<2) and P(1) + P(2) for the first part and P(2) for the second.

iii) The result is practically given to you. You just need to know how to go from the probability mass function to the cumulative distribution function.

Comment: Note that this is a rather elementary problem and some are voting to close.

Comment: +1 This is just the right approach to answering self-study questions: ask leading questions and provide informative hints.

Comment: @whuber I think I am learning.